# Blank XML Namespace processing With Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse a XML using python ,xml example snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<raml xmlns="raml21.xsd" version="2.1">
    <series xmlns="" scope="USA" name="Arizona">
        <header>
            <log action="created"/>
        </header>
        <x_ns color="Blue">
            <p name="timeZone">(GMT-10)</p>
        </x_ns>
        <x_ns color="Red">
            <p name="AvgHeight">175</p>
        </x_ns>
        <x_ns color="black">
            <p name="AvgWeight">235</p>
        </x_ns>
```

the problem is namespaces keeps changing so as an alternative I tried to read the xmlns string first then create a dicionary using namespaces using the below code

```
root = raw_xml.getroot()
namespace_temp1=root.tag.split("}")
namespace_temp2=namespace_temp1[0].strip('{')
namespaces_auto={}
tag_name =["x","y","z","w","v"]
ns_name=[namespace_temp2,namespace_temp2,namespace_temp2,namespace_temp2,namespace_temp2]

namespace_temp3=zip(tag_name,ns_name)
for tag,ns in namespace_temp3:
    namespaces_auto[tag]=ns
namespaces=namespaces_auto
```

to access a particular tag with namespace I am using the code as follows

```
for data in raw_xml.findall('x:x_ns',namespaces)
```

this pretty much solves the problem but gets stuck when the child node has blank xmlns as seen in the series tag (xmlns=""). Not Sure how to incorporate it in the code to check this condition.

Comment: Can you post a longer example of your XML? Say in a Github gist, if too long to fit well in the question? That snippet is not long enough to really get a sense of the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan , Added longer XML code.

Comment: Thank you. Based on what I see here, comprehending the file does not seem to depend on namespaces—neither namespace prefixes nor attributes. For such files, I usually strip all namespace information before the scrape/comprehension phase. In theory there are XML documents you can't fully understand without the namespace information; in practice they are exceedingly rare. Unless you have one of those very rare cases, I've found stripping NS information greatly simplifies parsing.

Comment: @Jonathan , can you please share your code how are you stripping the namespace..??